# Populate spinner based on a condition

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-spinner

I have created a registration form in which i have 2 spinners(State,Area) and AutoTextView city.When the user selects a particular state,the respective cites from that state should only be populated in that spinner  AutoTextView .For that i have created and asynck task and get the cites in form of json.But my problem is that the background task starts before user selects the State ,so always i am getting the 1st value of the state.

Code

```
public void onClick(View view) {

        str_first_name = first_name.getText().toString();
        str_last_name = last_name.getText().toString();
        str_mobile = mobile.getText().toString();
        str_city = city.getText().toString();
        str_area = area.getText().toString();





        //for state
        str_state = (String) state.getSelectedItem();
        state_short = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.State_Short);
        state_code = state_short[state.getSelectedItemPosition()];
        state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
               stateFull = (String) state.getSelectedItem();
                Log.e("State selected",""+stateFull);
                getCity getCity = new getCity();
                getCity.execute(stateFull);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });


        //for address
        str_address = address.getText().toString();



        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.bt_continue_1:


                if (str_first_name.equals("") || str_last_name.equals("") || str_gender.equals("Select Gender") || str_religion.equals("Select Religion") || str_age.equals("Select Age")) {
                    commonFunctions.showAlert(this, "INVALID", "Please fill all the mandatory details");
                    personal_info.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                    professional_info.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                    contact_info.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                } else {

                    header.setText("Contact Info");
                    personal_info.setAnimation(commonFunctions.animateLeft());
                    contact_info.setAnimation(commonFunctions.animateRight());
                    personal_info.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                    professional_info.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                    contact_info.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                }

                break;

            case R.id.bt_continue_2:



                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }
                });

                if (str_mobile.equals("") || str_state.equals("Select State") || str_city.equals("") || str_area.equals("") || str_address.equals("")) {


                    commonFunctions.showAlert(this, "INVALID", "Please fill all the mandatory details");
                    personal_info.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                    professional_info.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                    contact_info.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                    header.setText("Professional Info");


                    contact_info.setAnimation(commonFunctions.animateLeft());
                    professional_info.setAnimation(commonFunctions.animateRight());
                    personal_info.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                    contact_info.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                    professional_info.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;


            case R.id.bt_save:
//                AddUpdateJobResource async = new AddUpdateJobResource (personal_info.this, "0", "34588A34-E969-4723-84FE-E5409B66A5B7", "", str_first_name, str_last_name, gender_id, age_substring, nationality_id, "IND", "INDIA", state_code, str_state, str_city, str_area, str_address, str_mobile, profession_id, religion_id, "2", months_substring, yrs_substring, "0.00", "0.00", "hssuraksha");
//                async.execute ();
                AddResources addResources = new AddResources();
                addResources.execute();


        }

    }
```

Async Task

```
public class getCity extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
//            commonFunctions.showProgressBar(personal_info.this, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s.trim());
                JSONObject NewDataSet = jsonObject.getJSONObject("NewDataSet");
                JSONArray tableArray = NewDataSet.getJSONArray("Table");
                for (int i = 0; i < tableArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject table = tableArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String cityValues = table.getString("City_District_Name");
                    cityArray[i] = cityValues;
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(c, R.layout.textview_list, cityArray);
                    city.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
//            commonFunctions.showProgressBar(personal_info.this, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String response;
            response = HttpRequest.post("https://beta135.hamarisuraksha.com/web/WebService/HsJobService.asmx/getCityDistrictForStates").send("State_Name=" + strings[0]).body();
            response = response.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "").replaceAll("\n", "");
            Log.e("STate city", "" + response);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things here to look at:

1.) You are registering setOnItemSelectedListener for the spinner in onClick() method.So new setOnItemSelectedListener  is registered for each click.  Try registering setOnItemSelectedListener  for the Spinner only once in an activity.
2.)  Is selected attribute true for the spinner. I mean by default is the first one is selected? 
Also when is the onClick() method called?